# Powershell get-content ignore quoted delimiter

Tags: powershell, csv

Can powershell capture the delimiter of csv file correctly using get-content? By using get-content it will capture comma in the double quotation as delimiter too.
Example of file csv file data used:
[image]

Code of get-content tested:

```
$path1 = "C:\Users\Soung\Desktop\Datascreening\test1\testing.csv"
Get-Content $path1 | ForEach-Object {($_.Split($delimiter)).Count}
```

Result:

[image]

Remarks: Tested using import-csv method however import-csv will capture the result until 4th columns same as the header, row 5 & 6 which contain more than 4 columns of data are unable to capture correctly. Need to use get-content as need to process large sizes of files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count CSV columns without using Excel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668142/count-csv-columns-without-using-excel-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Import-Csv` cmdlet for that:

```
'"a,b",a,b' > test.txt
'"a,b",a,b' >> test.txt
Import-Csv test.txt
```

If the problema is that the `Import-Csv` only read as much entries in each row as there are headers you can always specify headers with `-Headers` parameter:

```
Import-CSV -Header @('1','2','3','4','5','6')
```

Comment: Hi, I already tested using Import-CSV, it will ignore the columns that over the header. Example on row 5, there are 6 columns, import-csv will read until 4th columns only.

Comment: you can always provide header value. i dont see a problema with that

Comment: Provide header value? Not really understand, isit means that provide a custom header value? Could u give an example?

Comment: `Import-CSV -Header @{'1','2','3','4','5','6'}`

Comment: So meaning that I need manually force the header always larger in size? Example a file with 40 header, so my script force write until header until 100 is it correct? Import-CSV -Header @{'1','2','3'.....,'99','100'}

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! Please edit your answer so I can mark it ask answered :)

Comment: ??? The `-Header` parameter expects a comma-separated list (or an array) of the column headers not a hash table, see [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-5.1). An array is enclosed by parenthesis `@(...)`, a hash table is enclosed by curly brackets `@{...}`, did any body test the answer or do I miss something?. Btw the good thing is that you can do something like this with an array: `Import-CSV -Header @(1..99)`

Comment: ah yes, sorry, my bad

Comment: I tried run my files for a whole day, and I notice import-csv performance still relatively slow compared to get-content for column checking, so isit there is no alternative method to solve it?

Comment: this is a completely different question, you should raise a new one