# Import-Csv slow performance

Tags: powershell, csv

I have plenty of CSV files which all are large in sizes, and I used PowerShell to create a script to check any miscount columns of every rows in the records. Previously I asked a few related question on the `Get-Content`, `Import-Csv`, Excel COM API.

[Count CSV columns without using Excel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668142/count-csv-columns-without-using-excel-api)

[Powershell get-content ignore quoted delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688320/powershell-get-content-ignore-quoted-delimiter)

I using `Import-Csv` as suggested and I noted the performance still relatively very slow. Averagely it took around 20 minutes to execute on 50k rows of records.

Here is the testing code snippet of `Import-Csv`:

```
$path = "testing.csv"
$headerlimit = @(1..15)
$result = Import-Csv $path -Header $headerlimit |
          ForEach {@($_.PSObject.Properties| Where {$_.Value -ne $Null}).Count}
$i = 0
$line = 1
foreach ($loop in $result) {
    if ($result[$i] -ne <header columns count value here>) {
        echo  "Line: $line "
        echo "Column Found:" $result[$i]
    }
    $i++
    $line++
}
```

So is that the problem source is from my looping statement caused the slowing in performance or PowerShell is slower in performance compared to other programming language such as C# when execute this kind of task?

Reference:

[Why cant PowerShell run loops fast ?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anantd/2014/07/25/why-cant-powershell-run-loops-fast/)

Update:
In my previous script, I log simple details as follow(sample log of final result what am i trying to achieved):

```
  > ...................#1 File Name: book2.csv, Header Cell Count: 6 ...........................

    > Row No    Column No           Result 
        > 3        9            Invalid Column Count: Found mismatch no of header column vs data column 
        > 5        6            No Data Found: No data found on this row
> Total Rows Found(Exclude Header): (5)
> Total Maximum Columns Found: (9)
```

I wish to check on the data to ensure the csv properly exported from application database or from user manual insert the records. Hence the file size will very huge and may contain errors on it.

Comment: Do you need to know per row how many columns are missing a value? (btw: I seriously doubt that your performance issue has anything to do with the reference you linked to. Powershell is creating a lot of objects and that's probably all there is to it. You should use measure-command on each individual statement to find the culprit but my guess would be the PSObject.Properties | Where piece)

Comment: When asking the third question about (more or less) the same topic I think it's time to take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve rather than what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for? Why are you trying to determine missing values, and what do you want to do with the result you're getting?

Comment: Hi, LievenKeersmaekers & Ansgar Wiechers, answer to the questions, I trying to check mismatch content data columns if not match with the header columns including less than or more than header column count. I need to log the  (row number + column number) that has mismatch column issues into a log file. The csv files are some generated from application/records which need ensure there are no errors after export it in order to process to next steps which is archive & store it. Hence, issues such as empty row & mismatch columns compared to header are needed to output it.

Comment: Isn't it better to understand why the application some times exports a column mismatch, with this understanding you might be able to fix it automatically. Besides if you do not understand why the number of columns can either too much or too less, how can you be sure that *any* row entry is correct when the number of columns matches? Technically, it could have both problems in one row: one unexpected column too much and one unexpected column too less...

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with the comment from [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers); Questions arise as:
*Do you really need line numbers or actually the items at the concerned lines?*
I have the feeling that you letting us help you to reinvent the wheel.

Anyways, to answer your question: PowerShell has a lot of cmdlets and commands, in a lot of cases you can do something with just a single command. Especially where performance is an issue, it is better to investigate in finding the right command then trying to program something yourself (and reinvent the wheel that performs less then the native solution).

In this specific case, use the `Where-Object` cmdlet, you can simply retrieve the concerned rows that are not aligned at once:

```
Import-Csv $path -Header $headerlimit | 
    Where {@($_.PSObject.Properties| Where {$_.Value -ne $Null}).Count -ne <header columns count value here>}
```